# Pocket authentication returns BadRequest with content-type 'application/json'

Tags: json, node.js, http-headers, pocket

I am retrieving access token for pocket api. I am able to do so successfully using a Http POST request with content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
{ 
  host: 'getpocket.com',
  path: '/v3/oauth/authorize',
  port: 443,
  method: 'POST',
  headers:
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'Content-Length': 79 } 
}
```

But pocket also supports content type as `application/json`.

```
{ 
  host: 'getpocket.com',
  path: '/v3/oauth/authorize',
  port: 443,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': 79 } 
}
```

But using this type of request returns me

> '400 Bad Request'

I am doing this on nodejs. Do i have to pass any extra details on this, like 'X-Accept'(dont know how do so).

Answer (score 1):

I think Pocket is reporting a bad request because you are sending form encoded data while declaring it as JSON in `Content-Type` Header.

If you want to *send* data to Pocket in JSON format, set `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8`.

If you want to *receive* data in JSON format set `X-Accept: application/json`.

To include custom headers in HTTP requests, just add the name value pair to `req.headers` before sending them. For example:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-Accept' : 'application/json'}
```

or:

```
req.headers['X-Accept'] = 'application/json'
```

Have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback.

Comment: Perhaps you are sending form encoded data while declaring it as JSON in Content-Type Header. I doubt this is the case because `Content-Length` is same in both requests you mentioned in question. You need to send JSON data to make it work.